# Error saving Activity state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-savedstate

I have 2 activities Main and Sub. Main calls Sub, Sub performs the operation and return the value to Main through an intent. Main stores the value.

This process is repeated till a bunch of times.
I am trying to save the state of Main using SavedInstanceState but it doesn't seem to work.

Also is there any other way I can return from Sub to Main such that Main's state is saved?

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("names",list);

    // etc.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("names");
}
```

Comment: If you finish the Activity, then clearly you no longer need its transient state. If the state is actually data and not just transient state, then you should be considering a different means of data persistence.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I removed finish() from the code, but a completely new activity is getting created. Do I have to put onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) before onCreate()?